# How to inject environment variables into custom-policies.json for an AWS Amplify Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify to set up my backend, and I have created a Lambda function through the Amplify CLI. I know that Amplify allows us to define custom policies for a Lambda function in custom-policies.json. My requirement is to use environment-specific values (like account ID, region, or other environment-specific data) in these policy definitions.

For instance, in a policy ARN like:

```
[
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["execute-api:Invoke"],
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/*/POST/*"]
  }
]
```

I want to replace region and `account-id` with values from my environment variables or some other dynamic source.

1. Is there a way to template or inject environment variables into the custom-policies.json file?
2. If direct templating isn't supported, are there any workarounds to achieve this?

Any guidance or best practices regarding this would be greatly appreciated!